# Convert milliseconds to date in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have to convert milliseconds to date with precision. I have made following attempts but can't get expected date:

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:1409030961192]

[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1409030961192];

[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1409030961192];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you got that time from a Java back end?

Anyway, this will convert to a date of... `Wed, 31 May 46620 17:13:12 GMT`

To get a more sensible date just remove the last three digits i.e. divide by 1000.0 (to keep milliseconds).

This will then give... `Tue, 26 Aug 2014 05:29:21 GMT`

Which is probably what you're looking for.

Oh, and use the method...

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1409030961];
```

You can use [this website](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) to mess around with different times to see what they convert to.

Comment: An NSTimeInterval is a double, so divide by `1000.0`, which retains the millisecond precision (mostly)

Comment: Asking for the date 'with precision' would seem to imply that he wants to retain the milliseconds in the NSDate. Milliseconds matter to computers - if it was being used to determine a server/client time difference then rounding it would lose a lot of precision